# Configuring Multiple sites in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a general query about configuring multiple sites in Sitecore.

To simplify i would split the question in 2 parts:

1. I have multiple sites created under a single instance of sitecore on my Win XP machine for e.g `http://www.site1.com/`, `http://www.site2.com` etc

   I then configured my web.config to reflect the multiple sites like so...

   ```xml
   <sites>
     <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" .../>
     <site name="website1" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" hostName="www.site1.com" startItem="/home1" database="web" .../>

     ...
   </sites>
   ```

   Then i made the corresponding host entry in the hosts file.

   This works fine and i am able to access multiple sites on a browser.

   **Problem:**
   The same steps repeated on a Win 2008 R2 system does not work. Do i need to do any additional configuration?
2. I have downloaded and installed a Multiple Sites Manager package on my existing sitecore installation.
   After doing that, my existing sites are not loading anymore.
   What is going wrong here.

   I have checked for any web.config entries, or any additional configuration files created in the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\<site>\website` folder but could not find anything.

   Any solutions/pointers in this regard would help.

Comment: What exactly does not work on Win 2008 R2? What kind of error do you see?

Comment: By "does not work" i mean, the site does not load; i m trying to access the different sites using the same domain as i specified in my Win XP system.

Comment: I can see you've been given a link to this article at SDN forum: http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/10/how-to-multisite-in-sitecore.aspx. I would strongly recommend to verify your setup against it before moving further. Probably, it's a kind of oversight in configuration which can hardly be seen now from the info you provided...

Comment: I have already gone through that link...but that does not address my problem. It talks about configuring multiple sites manually (i.e not using multiple sites manager), and does not talk anything about configuring multiple sites in a win 2008 R2 environment.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause could be that you do not have the correct bindings set up in IIS 7 for the hostnames mapped in your web.config (unless you have a wildcard binding already)?

Answer (score 1):

It may be the order of your  tags.  Generally these should go from most explicit to most default.  The second one specifies a hostname, so this should go above the one without the hostname.

- Daniel

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you access the server efrom a remote client PC - you would need to update the hosts file on the remote client PC, or create an actual host entry in the DNS records.

Is the browser running on the server, or on a remote client?

Regards,

-John